# How to convert React Class Component fields into hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I know the gist of converting React Class components to functional components, but I found an instance where I nor my searching on the internet know the answer.

```
export default class Counter extends Component<Props, State> {
    count = 0

    updateCount = ()=> this.count +=1

    render() {
        return <div onClick={this.updateCount}>{this.count}</div>
    }
}
```

Ignore the ugliness of the class, but how would i carry the count over into a functional component, with useRef?

The reason I ask is because in another class i am trying to convert, I have an async PromisePool running, that updates the downloaded variable each time a promise finishes, and when I tried to put `downloaded` into the state, it would always rerender the component and lose the data.

Comment: try keep close to original component. sample you have provided does not make sense since it is not re-rendered after count is updated. show how your PromisePool is updated and how affects rendering result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `useRef`, you can create a variable which is not initialized on each re-render. The above component would look like

```
export default () => {
    const count = useRef(0);

    const updateCount = ()=> count.current +=1

    render() {
        return <div onClick={updateCount}>{count}</div>
    }
}
```

However, you must know that updating a ref doesn't cause a re-render and hence updated value won't reflect in render

If you wish to trigger a re-render, make use of `useState` instead

```
export default () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    const updateCount = ()=> setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);

    render() {
        return <div onClick={updateCount}>{count}</div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a direct example of moving the component over to a functional component. The count will remain in use as long as the component doesn't fully remount. It will remain even after re-renders.

```
export default function Counter(){
    const [count,setCount] = useState(0);
    return <div onClick={()=>setCount(count=>count+1)}>{count}</div>
}
```

Unless you are remounting this component by using a different key or changing the dom above it (i.e. adding a wrapping div after your promise finishes), then this should work fine (but in the instance of remounting, the class component would also reset it's counter).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot carry the updated value of count with useRef since no rerender occurs when count is updated. useRef is for persisting an object in a component over multiple renders.

A possible solution for your PromisePools issue: Instead of converting the parent into a functional component, make use of the shouldComponentUpdate() lifecycle method in your class component to prevent a rerender of the child component when the state is changed.

Take a look at the lifecycle docs for more info:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate